# Using Java generics in an anonymous inner class

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I have edited my example to show a more practical example of what I'm trying to achieve. I would like to understand what I should specify as the second type when instantiating the new TableCell object within the Lambda expression, given the types being passed into the method.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
void setTableCellStuff (TableColumn <Object, ?> tableCell) {
    tableCell.setCellFactory(arg0 -> 
        new TableCell <Object, ?> () // cannot use ? in instantiator.
    );
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to reuse the `col` variable? Would you have thie problem if you used a new variable every time? There could be an issue with object lifetime, but that's impossible to tell from this little bit of code.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi @SeverityOne, thanks for your comment. As I said in my question I could declare a new variable for each column, but I was trying to be economical with my typing, particularly as I have about 30 columns. So I wanted to know if what I'm doing is possible, and also hoping to understand a little bit more about generics. Thanks!

Comment: @ohlec here you are:

     TableColumn <Object, ?> col = new TableColumn <Object, Integer> ("Reference");
     col.setCellFactory(arg -> 
      new TableCell <Object, ?> () {
       
      }
     );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
<T> void setTableCellStuff (TableColumn <Object, T> tableCell) {
    tableCell.setCellFactory(arg0 -> 
        new TableCell <Object, T> ()
    );
}
```

`T` could still be any type, but this way the type of table cell you construct matches the type of column you have.

Comment: Thanks very much. I've never seen that before a method before, will have to look into that!

Comment: it's also possible to write `new TableCell<>()`